# How i get Facebook survey data and print?

Tags: facebook, get, survey

A survey will be opened on Facebook and I need to get the voting percentage data of this survey live. The received data will automatically be saved in the specific new text document on the desktop. It will not download extra new files. It will just update the existing one. So I'm going to add that new text document to OBS. It will be presented to viewers in the group live on OBS. In this way, current data will flow. Do I have the opportunity to do this? Is it difficult? I would be grateful if you inform me.

idk. just i want to know.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know exactly how you would go about achieving something like that. But I have maybe some suggestions that can hopefully put you on the right path. I've recently used Selenium within Python. It is a library that makes use of a browser driver. You can pass it a link to a website, and access the HTML elements of that website which can then be used to interact with programmatically. In your case you could write your Python program to open Facebook (using selenium library). Store the HTML contents that contain the values u want, like survey numbers. (also using selenium library). And then use a different library to write those values to a txt file. The only library you'd need to install is the Selenium one. I advice you to look up the Selenium tutorial by Tech with Tim on YouTube. I think the hardest part is finding a way to keep your txt file in sync with the survey, since it requires you to refresh the facebook page. And since you want to do that automatically. That can be difficult. But I hope this helps!